# How to make asyncore not block?

Tags: python, asyncore

I am using below code from the below link. My understanding is asyncore.loop() will print LOOP_DONE instead of waiting for the data to be delivered. Instead, the LOOP_DONE is printed only after all the data has been read. Why is loop() blocking?

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/pymotw-asyncore.html

```
import asyncore
import logging
import socket
from cStringIO import StringIO
import urlparse
class HttpClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.url)
        self.parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.write_buffer = 'GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' % self.url
        self.read_buffer = StringIO()
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        address = (self.parsed_url.netloc, 80)
        self.logger.debug('connecting to %s', address)
        self.connect(address)

    def handle_connect(self):
        self.logger.debug('handle_connect()')

    def handle_close(self):
        self.logger.debug('handle_close()')
        self.close()

    def writable(self):
        is_writable = (len(self.write_buffer) > 0)
        if is_writable:
            self.logger.debug('writable() -> %s', is_writable)
        return is_writable

    def readable(self):
        self.logger.debug('readable() -> True')
        return True

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.write_buffer)
        self.logger.debug('handle_write() -> "%s"', self.write_buffer[:sent])
        self.write_buffer = self.write_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        self.logger.debug('handle_read() -> %d bytes', len(data))
        self.read_buffer.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(name)s: %(message)s',
                        )
    clients = []
    for i in range(10):
        clients.append(HttpClient('http://www.python.org/'))
    #clients = [
    #    HttpClient('http://www.python.org/'),
    #    HttpClient('http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/contents.html'),
    #]

    logging.debug('LOOP STARTING')
    asyncore.loop()
    logging.debug('LOOP DONE')

    for c in clients:
        response_body = c.read_buffer.getvalue()
        print c.url, 'got', len(response_body), 'bytes'
```

Comment: `asyncore.loop()` is an event loop.

Comment: That's a question for Google.

Comment: maybe you want http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html ?

Comment: Thanks reading the wikipedia article now, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop. However, still confused about the purpose of asynchronous I/O and the practical examples.

Comment: asyncore.loop() enter a polling loop that terminates after count passes or **all open channels have been closed**.